# How to create and manage a npm process in electron

Tags: node.js, process, electron

I'm trying to make this little QoL app that can trigger my scripts inside package.json of any project I throw at it (react, polymer, etc.).

So far, it works as it should. At least until I kill the app or want to terminate the specific process (like using ctrl+c while running a npm start in a console).

I'm currently calling the command this way:

```
const exec = require("child_process").execFile;
...
let ps = exec("command.bat", [path, command], (error, stdout, stderr)=>{}) //command.bat contains only: cd "%1" \n npm "%2"
```

Previously I've used [node-powershell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-powershell) like so:

```
const Shell = require('node-powershell');
...
let sh = new Shell();
sh.addCommand(`cd ${fs.realpathSync(path)}`);
sh.addCommand(`npm ${command}`);
sh.invoke();
```

And I've already tried using [ps-tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ps-tree) in hopes that this will list all the processes started by my process so I can kill them but no luck and because it creates additional process or two it's getting out of hands really quickly.

```
const cp = require('child_process');
...
psTree(ps.pid, function (err, children) {
    cp.spawn('kill', ['-9'].concat(children.map(function (p) { return p.PID })));
});
```

So if there is some solution I would be really grateful. I'm also open to any different solution if there is any.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try passing `SIGKILL`  signal to exec process

Comment: Like this? `exec("command.bat", [path, command], {killSignal: "SIGKILL"}, (error, stdout, stderr)=>{})` If so, it doesn't work either.

Comment: please refer this [exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) and add accordingly

Comment: Ok so I've changed the execFile for exec and changed the attributes accordingly but still no change, the main process dies but it still leaves two node.js:Server-side Javascript processes and two console window hosts behind. 
Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, my electron/nodejs knowledge is three days old.